# How to merge dynamic range of cells in one specific column?

Tags: excel, vba

For e.g. I have three values (numbers) in cells B1, B2 and B3. These explain how many cells I should merge in column A. 
For example B1 = 6, B2 =3 and B3 = 2  then I want to merge cell range A16 to A22 (16+6), then A23 to A26 should be a new merged range and the last merged range should be A27 to A29.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show the code that you have already written?

I think you have to use the function `Merge` in your range.

The code below works great for me :

```
Sub merge()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim i3 As Integer
    i = Range("B1")
    i2 = Range("B2")
    i3 = Range("B3")
    Range("A1:A" & i).merge
    Range("A" & (i + 1) & ":A" & (i + i2)).merge
    Range("A" & (i + i2 + 1) & ":A" & (i + i2 + i3)).merge
End Sub
```